# Cell size changing when cropping a raster

Tags: r, extract-by-mask

I am cropping a large raster with the extent of a smaller one.

The printout for large:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 6327, 12697, 80333919  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 463.3127, 463.3127  (x, y)
extent      : -9632735, -3750053, 4869417, 7800796  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
names       : large 
values      : 0, 4976998  (min, max)
```

the printout for small:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 2400, 2400, 5760000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 463.3127, 463.3127  (x, y)
extent      : -4447802, -3335852, 5559753, 6671703  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
names       : small
```

Therefore, I want the cropped raster to have the same dimensions, resolution and extent of `small`.

I am attempting this like so:

```
library(raster)

large <- raster ("C:/large.tif")
small <- raster ("C:/small.tif")

clip_extent = extent(ras)

#clip
clipped <- crop(large, small)
extent(clipped) <- extent(small)
```

but the output changes the resolution and dimensions:

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 2400, 1506, 3614400  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 738.347, 463.3127  (x, y)
extent      : -4447802, -3335852, 5559753, 6671703  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs 
values      : 187927, 2240075  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that easily with the **gdalUtils** package.

Here I create the data first and store it as tif:

```
require(raster)

large <- raster(nrow=6327, ncol=12697,
                xmn=-9632735, xmx=-3750053, ymn=4869417, ymx=7800796,
                crs="+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs",
                resolution=c(463.3127, 463.3127))
values(large) <- 1: ncell(large)

small <- raster(nrow=2400, ncol=2400,
                xmn=-4447802, xmx=-3335852, ymn=5559753, ymx=6671703,
                crs="+proj=sinu +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371007.181 +b=6371007.181 +units=m +no_defs",
                resolution=c(463.3127, 463.3127))
values(small) <- 1:ncell(small)

writeRaster(large, "large.tif")
writeRaster(small, "small.tif")
```

Then you can use `align_rasters` and test if the resolution and extent is equal to the small raster (which in my case is true):

```
require(gdalUtils)

clipped <- align_rasters("large.tif", "small.tif", "clipped.tif", output_Raster=TRUE)

extent(clipped) == extent(small)
res(clipped) == res(small)
```